# Ruby's Gemfile equivalent for Android & Gradle with online git integration?

Tags: android, git, build.gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My project needs to use external libraries that are located in other remote git repositories.

So far to use them I would have download the library to my computer and add them to my application git repository.
There are some disadvantages of that.

So, I was wondering is there a nice smooth solution like the iOS have with their [Cocoa pods](http://cocoapods.org/) where can they simply add those repository as a pod (or Ruby's `Gemfile`).
looking somethings simple like:

```
pod 'SDK', :git => 'git://github.com/MySdkToDownload.git'
```

My Android project works with `Gradle`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between Java and Ruby is that Java projects have to be compiled somehow at some step in the process of importing where Ruby only copies the project in its classpath (if I'm not mistaken). So you need a compiled/packed build for your app.

Gradle can use a lot of things and AFAIK it uses mainly Maven, so you have multiple options:

- Import your library as Module in your Android Studio/IntelliJ Project
- Compile the external library as .jar (if it's only code) and put it in /libs/ and import it with compile files('libs/mylibrary.jar')
- Use a version of that library that would be present in the [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/) and import it as you import any other mvn dependency, for instance EventBus: compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.0.2'
- Install for your company a kind of your-own-maven-repo with [Sonatype Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), upload in it your .aar or .jar to it and then add repository to the repositories, and add the library dependency.

Comment: A couple of minutes googling turned up this gradle plugin for git repos https://github.com/marceloemanoel/gradle-git-repository-plugin